# If else in JSP to display different views

Tags: jsp

I am using below if else in JSP two display either of two view. But this is not showing any content on page. What is wrong in this code ?

```
<%@ taglib prefix='c' uri='http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core' %>
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${myVariable}">
        <jsp:include page="view1.jsp" />
    </c:when>
   <c:otherwise>
       <jsp:include page="view2.jsp" />
   </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: Your code works for me. All I added was the following line. <%pageContext.setAttribute("myVariable", false);%>

Comment: yes, when i add single line between <c:when test="${myVariable}"> </c:when>. It's getting displayed. When i add same line in view1.jsp. , It's not getting displayed.

Comment: I don't understand what you are telling me. What happens when the includes are placed on the main page outside of the choose tag? Are the JSPs found and their outputs included into the output of the main page?